# yubikey not functioning with qutebrowser

Tags: chromium, yubico

I've been using yubikey for a while with chrome, but have recently discovered how much I like using qutebrowser.

Today I was trying to log into github to make a comment and couldn't finish with my yubikey. Github told me something went 'really wrong' and asked me to press the button or reinsert my key. Did both...nothing.

when I pressed the button, qute dumped me into insert mode. Thought maybe it was a problem with the chromium engine, but downloaded chromium and it works fine. I'm guessing it has something to do with the python integration, but not sure.

So long story short? Is it possible to use the yubikey with qutebrowser or am I going to have to move to a vimium like setup in chrome or firefox?

Comment: Is this an https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic question? What does this have to do with coding? To me this sounds more like you should ask Yubico/QuteBrowser team for help, not at StackOverflow, don't you think so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the project’s GitHub issues, U2F support appears to be an open issue at this time.

https://github.com/qutebrowser/qutebrowser/issues/3043

Comment: Thanks. so sorry to the up the forum. I swear I searched before I posted 